# Excel macro to LibreOffice

Tags: excel, libreoffice, vba

I have an .XLS file with a VBA Macro. What would be the fastest way to use it with LibreOffice?  I've tried the "Option VBASupport 1" in the VBA Project part, but my buttons do not call functions correctly. Is it possible to translate it into LO Basic easily? Is it better to keep it VBA and apply some modifications?

Comment: I did not try on last version of LibreOffice, but I had to do same thing some years ago. I had to rewrite everything, because if the basic language is more or less the same, the Microsoft objects were not known in OpenOffice environment.

Answer (score 5):

For the most part the two do not work together.  MSO uses VBA and LO uses code based on the LibreOffice API. The objects and methods in each are different, thereby leading to incompatibility. You will probably have to reprogram it, sorry.

Comment: from LibreOffice.org: "The most recent versions of LibreOffice can run some Excel Visual Basic scripts if you enable this feature at LibreOffice - PreferencesTools - Options - Load/Save - VBA Properties". Try upgrading LO and see if that helps.